# Magento 2 function returns same each time

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm writing some code for my product page to get some yes/no attributes that are in two seperate attribute groups, which I can then use to display an image if the attribute has a value of 1 (yes).

Here is the code in the block (Product.php):

```
/**
 * Gets the attribute group of a product via its ID
 *
 * @param $groupID int: the attribute group ID
 * @return collection of product attributes
 */
public function getAttributeGroup($groupId) {
    return $this->attributeCollection->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId);
}

/**
 * Gets the information of an attribute in an array
 *
 * @param $label string: the label of the attribute
 * @param $code string: the code of the attribute
 * @param $loadOption boolean: whether to load the options
 * @return array: the array with the info
 */
public function getAttributeArray($label, $code, $loadOption = false) {
    $value = (
        $loadOption ?
        $this->product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getValue($this->product) :
        $this->product->getData($code)
    );
    if($value) {
        $res = array();
        $res["label"] = $label;
        $res["value"] = $value;
        return $res;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Displays key stage and other icons on product page
 *
 * @param $groupId int: the attribute group ID
 * @return array/boolean: the array with the info or false
 */
public function displayIcons($groupId) {
    $icons = $this->getAttributeGroup($groupId);
    if (!$icons) {
        throw new Exception('Could not get attribute group.');
    }
    $iconAttributes = array();
    foreach($icons as $icon) {
        $data = $icon->getData();
        if (!$data) {
            throw new Exception('Could not get attribute data.');
        }
        $iconAttribute = $this->getAttributeArray($data["frontend_label"], $data["attribute_code"]);
        if ($iconAttribute["value"] == 1) {
            $iconAttribute["code"] = $data["attribute_code"];
            array_push($iconAttributes, $iconAttribute);
        }
    }
    return $iconAttributes;
}
```

And in the product.phtml:

```
try {
    $icons = $block->displayIcons(34);
    $keyStageIcons = $block->displayIcons(35);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

print_r($icons);
print_r($keyStageIcons);
```

The problem is that it doesn't get the result of the second group correctly. When I print at the end I get the first group twice:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Competitive Play
            [value] => 1
            [code] => competitive
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Co-Operative Play
            [value] => 1
            [code] => coopplay
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Hand-eye Co-ordination
            [value] => 1
            [code] => handeye
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => Physical Fitness
            [value] => 1
            [code] => physical
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Competitive Play
            [value] => 1
            [code] => competitive
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Co-Operative Play
            [value] => 1
            [code] => coopplay
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Hand-eye Co-ordination
            [value] => 1
            [code] => handeye
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => Physical Fitness
            [value] => 1
            [code] => physical
        )

)
```

If I flip around the function calls and put $keyStageIcons first then I get that one twice:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Key Stage 1
            [value] => 1
            [code] => ks1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Key Stage 2
            [value] => 1
            [code] => ks2
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Key Stage 1
            [value] => 1
            [code] => ks1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Key Stage 2
            [value] => 1
            [code] => ks2
        )

)
```

Why would it not get me the second group when I call the function again? It's as if the variables of my displayIcons function are not being reset each time it is called.

Comment: Whats the result when u call : $icons = $block->displayIcons(34);
    $keyStageIcons = $block->displayIcons(null); ?

Comment: @Shan same result, I get the same group twice.